# Visualização HTML do campo

Tags: html

Eu tenho um campo input onde é trago o valor do banco, que utilizo desta forma:

```
<input asp-for="TICMS" name="TICMS" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" class="form-control" />
```

Porém surgiu a seguinte dúvida: Este campo ele não é alterado pelo usuário, ele é apenas alterado por meios de contas via `javascript` então não há necessidade de aparecer como um `textbox`, porém eu preciso que ele seja salvo no banco, pois podem haver alterações, qual seria a melhor forma dele aparecer ?
Eu tentei algo como:

```
 @Html.Raw(model.TICMS);
```

Porém ele não salva no banco se estiver desta forma. Qual a melhor saída?

**EDIT**

Se eu tiro as bordas via css, e coloco `readonly` o campo fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mas se o campo não pode ser alterado, por que ele tem um evento *keypress*?

Comment: @RicardoPontual foi colocado antes destas condições. Antes era possível esta alteração, como é uma conta padrão, ela é feita conforme os dados inseridos na tabela, ela é feita via `javascript`, então ela precisa ser visível, e precisa ser salva no banco.

Comment: tentou usar o parametro: `readonly="true"`

Comment: entendi. nesse caso, você pode usar um outro elemento, como `span` por exemplo, que aceita html também

Comment: Mas desta forma eu consigo alterá-lo via `javascript` e salvar no banco igual os elementos `inputs` ?

Comment: Pq não o estiliza com CSS, tira as bordas e deixa ele readonly. Vai ficar com aparência de texto, mas, será um input normal que não dá para editar.

Comment: Eu tenho o css, porém se eu coloco ele em readonly o campo fica como se tivesse desabilitado, ai fica a aparência da caixa de texto.

Comment: Sim consegue, e também postar os valores para a model, basta que use o name/id correto de acordo com a model. Você pode também usar o atributo `readonly` no input que vai funcionar, só não pode desabilitar porque senão ele não será postado para a model.

Comment: @RicardoPontual tem algum exemplo pra me auxiliar?

Comment: Se ele nunca vai ser alterado, porque não mostrar em um `<span>` e ter um `<input type="hidden">` com esse valor?

Comment: basta trocar o input por label: `<label asp-for="TICMS" name="TICMS" ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, transformar o `input` em algo que não se parece um `input` acho que não é adequado... Mas se é o que vc quer aqui tem um exemplo que pode te servir.

Acredito que vc está usando Bootstrap, pois notei a classe `form-control` no seu `input` então tive que considerar isso no CSS que fiz. Primeiro eu dei um `all:unset` para tentar limpar ao máximo os estilos default do `input` do Bootstrap, porém a hierarquia do CSS do Bootstrap é muito forte e precisei usar alguns *`!important`* para remover tudo mesmo!

Veja como ficou no modelo abaixo:

```css
.form-control.labelcss {
    all:unset;
    border:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;

}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <input asp-for="TICMS" value="input customizado" name="TICMS" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" readonly class="form-control labelcss" />
        <label for="">isso é um label</label>
        <input asp-for="TICMS" value="input padrão com readonly" readonly name="TICMS" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))"  class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Deu certo Hugo, obrigado. Era isto mesmo que eu precisava.

Comment: @marianac_costa legal que deu certo! Eu não sou desenvolvedor propriamente dito, então leve em consideração os comentários dos amigos. Eu sei que da forma que fiz vai resolver seu problema, mas não sei se é a melhor opção, ou se é a opção que um programador faria rss :) Boa sorte no projeto!

Answer (score 0):

`<input asp-for="TICMS" name="TICMS" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" class="form-control" type="hidden"/>`

Coloca ele como `type="hidden"`, assim o usuário não vai ver ele, mas vai estar lá :)

Comment: Mas eu preciso que ele seja mostrado a fim de consulta, e ele pode ser "alterado", então precisa ser visível, para que o usuário veja as informações. Esses campos são resultados de outras contas, e precisa de visíveis e salvos.

Comment: Então coloca assim: `<input asp-for="TICMS" name="TICMS" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" class="form-control" readonly/>` Assim ele vai ficar somente leitura, o usuário não pode alterar, e pode ver

Comment: Eu queria que ele ficasse com um aspecto de `label`, por questão de estética.